# comparing columns by ignoring null values (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

data frame:

```
         data=pd.DataFrame({'name':['A','B','C'],
          'rank':[np.nan,2,3],
          'rank1':[2,np.nan,2],
          'rank2':[3,1,np.nan],
          'rank4':[4,2,3]})
```

my code:

```
           data['Diff']=np.where((data['rank']<data['rank1'])&(data['rank1']<data['rank2'])&(data['rank2']<data['rank4']),1,0)
```

requirement ignore null and compare rest of numeric values want diff of A to be 1 (if the rank is continuously increasing ignore null)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can `filter` the `rank` like columns, then forward fill on `axis=1` to propagate last valid value, then calculate `diff` along `axis=1` to check for monotonicity

```
r = df.filter(like='rank')
data['diff'] = r.ffill(1).diff(axis=1).fillna(0).ge(0).all(1)
```

---

```
  name  rank  rank1  rank2  rank4   diff
0    A   NaN    2.0    3.0      4   True
1    B   2.0    NaN    1.0      2  False
2    C   3.0    2.0    NaN      3  False
```

Comment: yeah it works ,just wanted to know if it has  3 nan if I want to ignore s .i mean 4 nan nan nan should be false how to achieve this

Comment: @sra Well that seems different requirement, because in the original question you have stated that you want to *ignore* the `NaN` values while checking for monotonicity

Comment: @sra BTW in that case you can use `r.ffill(1).diff(axis=1).fillna(0).ge(0).all(1) & r.count(1).gt(1)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `dropna` and then `is_monotonic`.

```
df['Diff'] = df.set_index('name').apply(lambda x: int(x.dropna().is_monotonic), 1)
```

OR you can use this to be more specific about the difference.

```
df = df.set_index('name').apply(lambda x: int(all(x.dropna().diff().fillna(1).eq(1))), 1)
```